# The term 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet in VSTS Task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

All of sudden I m getting the error

"2018-08-30T06:19:30.8460321Z ##[error]The term 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
" while executing PS task in VSTS .

My PS task has simple Write-Host $variable statement, it worked till y'day and something went wrong, tried rebooting target machine, ensured PS is available etc.

Any debugging steps please ?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a VSTS hosted agent (or) your own agent?

Comment: Hello. My own agent

Comment: Then the below answer might be work for you i guess! Isn't it?

Comment: Path exists but it gives same error .

Comment: Did the normal `powershell.exe` in the `cmd` works within your agent ?

Comment: @Jayendran yes . It works in agent.

Comment: Run the build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the logs for powershell task here.

Comment: @user2153844 Please check the agent [capabilities](https://www.marcusfelling.com/blog/2017/tfsvsts-build-system-capabilities-demands/) and find the actual path of powershell.exe

Answer (score 22):

Just in case somebody gets this error message on a hosted vm. I had the same issue and it was caused by a Pipeline variable called "Path". So just be smarter than me and don't name your variables like that.

This is what you definitely should avoid:
[image]

Comment: Had the exact same issue, thanks for finding this out!

Comment: Awesome answer thanks for the help, my exact issue.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to these steps:

1. Check **Path** variable of **System variables**
2. By default, there is `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` item, if it isn’t existing, please add related path that contains PowerShell.exe to the Path variable
3. Restart your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Check the environment variables on the machine - the "Path" variable should have the path to the Windows PowerShell directory in system32

[image: Environment Variables - Path]

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with Inline PS script, any script error throws .

The term 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Created a new release definition and it worked

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that release definitions created before is not having the same issue but if I add a new VSTS-task for PowerShell (Microsoft version) to a release definition it is unable to recognize powershell. I am wondering whether they pushed a change to the task and it broke something. My agent path directory is correct.

As an alternative, I am using a 3rd party developer's task. https://thinkrethink.net/2016/05/20/using-the-inline-powershell-vsts-task/